# Scala ambiguous case class generated and companion apply method

Tags: scala

Given following code:

```
case class Foo(bar: String)
object Foo{
  def apply(bar: String): Foo = Foo(bar)
}
```

If I was to call `Foo("foo")` I would end up with an infinite recursive call to `def apply(bar: String)`. Of course, I could fix this problem by changing my apply implementation to `def apply(bar: String): Foo = new Foo(bar)`. However, if I understand correctly, an apply method is generated for case classes with all their constructor parameters. My question then is two-fold:

1) If I myself wrote and then automatically generated a `Foo.apply(bar: String): Foo`, why do I not get a compilation error complaining about duplicate method definitions?

and

2) If generated method has a different signature, how can I call it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do I not get a compilation error complaining about duplicate method definitions?

Because your `apply()` code replaces the `case class` auto-generated code. They don't exist at the same time.

This can be demonstrated by compiling your code but dumping the intermediate state after the "typer" phase (phase 4) of the compilation.

```
%%> cat so.sc
case class Foo(bar: String)
object Foo{
  def apply(bar: String): Foo = Foo(bar)
}
%%> scalac -Xprint:4 so.sc | less
```

The resulting output has only one `object` with only one `apply()` method.

```
  object Foo extends scala.AnyRef with Serializable {
    def <init>(): Foo.type = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def apply(bar: String): Foo = Foo.apply(bar);
    case <synthetic> def unapply(x$0: Foo): Option[String] = if (x$0.==(null))
      scala.None
    else
      Some.apply[String](x$0.bar);
    <synthetic> private def readResolve(): Object = Foo
  }
```

As you can see, the recursive `apply()` method resides amidst the auto-generated `<synthetic>` code.